# I have large records in my data table with 37 columns and data crash in print page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I have near about `200` records in my data table with `37` columns and in this, I have a checkbox for columns select and show only selected checkbox columns in print page out of `37` columns but it shows only 9 to 10 columns in print page.
How can I show large columns in print page?
[image]

View:

```
  <section class="content">
         <div class="table-responsive">
           <table id="loading_sheet_table" class="table table-bordered  table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;">
          </table>
       </div>
    </section>
  </form>
    <button id="print" name="print"  onclick="printContent('print_loading_sheet')" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary fa fa-newspaper-o col-10 offset-1" style="margin-top: 35px; margin-bottom: 25px;" data-clicked="unclicked"> Print Loading Sheet Report</button>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
               url :"<?php echo base_url(); ?>booking/report/loading_sheet/LoadingSheetController/loadingSheet",
               type: 'POST',               
               data: {
                ac_type:ac_type,
                Station:Station,
                MainStaion:MainStaion
               },
               dataType: "html",
               success: function(data){

                  $('#loading_sheet_table').html(data);

               },async:false,
               error:function(data){
                console.log('error occured during featch');
                /*alertify.error("error message"+data);*/
               }
           });
       });

  function printContent(e1) {
     event.preventDefault();
          var allVals = [];
        $('input[name=selectedrecord]:not(:checked').each(function() {
           allVals.push($(this).val());
           });
             allVals.forEach(function(i){
            $('tr').each(function(){
            $(this).find('td, th').eq(i-1).css({
                       display:'none'
           });
        });
      });
      $('input[name=selectedrecord]').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //hiding Check box on print page
      var restorepage     = document.innterHTML;
      var printContent    = document.getElementById(e1).innterHTML;
      document.innterHTML = printContent;
      window.print();
      document.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"; 
   }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function loadingSheet(){
         $ac_type  = $this->input->post('ac_type');
         $to       = $this->input->post('Station');
         $formData = array();
         $data     = array(
                   'ac_type'           => $ac_type,                
                   'station'           => $to,
              ); 
          $modResult = $this->sendValues->receivingSheetOfStationwise($data,$brnachId); 
          ?>

     <form role="form" id="bilties" name="bilties" method="post">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="loading_sheet_table" class="table table-bordered  table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;" >
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th class="col1"><input   type="checkbox" name="selectedrecord" class="checkbox" value="1"><br>SR No</th>
                  <th class="col2"><input   type="checkbox" name="selectedrecord" class="checkbox" value="2"><br>Bilty Id</th>
                  <th class="col37"><input   type="checkbox" name="selectedrecord" class="checkbox" value="37"><br>Grand Total</th>//last record(37)
                 </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach($modResult as $bilty):?>
                  <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $bilty->id;?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $bilty->lr_no;?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $bilty->lr_grand_total;?></td>//last record(37)
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>              
                </tbody> 
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Model:

```
public function receivingSheetOfStationwise($data){
           extract($data);
           $this->db->select('*');
           $this->db->from('bilty');
           $this->db->where('lr_to',$station);
           $this->db->where('status', 'active');
           $this->db->order_by('b.lr_no','asc');
           $query=$this->db->get();
           return $query->result();
     }
```

I have only two problems,
1)How to handle large record like 500 records in my data table.
2)How I can show large columns after select checkbox in print page.

For reports in .Net crystal, reports are used what I use in my Codeigniter for data table reports.

Comment: 500 records are not anywhere close to large.

Comment: @JayBlanchard in the above image It gives me `Page Unresponsive` alert message

Comment: Print smaller, print less or print multiple pages. That are your options.

Answer (score 1):

Use dompdf or tcpdf as window print will work for small pages.

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/TCPDF-Integration